# How to lock Decimal Symbol when downloading CSV file in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, csv, download, axios, blob

I have a working solution to download a CSV file produced by my API with axios. (see code below)

My problem is that depending on the ***Decimal Symbol*** set in the Region of Windows, the numbers in the CSV files are not always in the right format.

For example :

- If my decimal symbol is ".", the numbers in the CVS file will be saved as 122.33
- If my decimal symbol is ",", the numbers in the CVS file will be saved as 122,33

Is there a way to "lock" this setting, so when the javascript create the CSV file from the blob and download it, the decimal symbol is ALWAYS "."?

Here is my code :

```
getWithParams: (route, mutation, commit, payload) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    commit('setIsLoading', true);
    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    payload.params.forEach((element) => {
      params.append(element.param, element.value);
    });
    axios.get(`${apiURL}${route}`, { params, responseType: 'blob' }).then((response) => {
      FileDownload(response.data, 'QueryResults.csv');
      commit('setIsLoading', false);
      resolve(response);
    }).catch((error) => {
      reject(helpers.setError(error.message));
    }).finally(() => {
      commit('setIsLoading', false);
    });
  }),
```

Notes :

- I cannot ask users to change their region parameter in Windows
- The delimiter in the CSV file are ; to make sure it won't get confuse with the decimal symbol ,

Comment: Isn't this a server side issue? Why is the client side code relevant?

Comment: @CallumMorrisson Depending on the computer making the call, the resulting CSV changes with , or . on the same server.

Comment: But it is the server creating the CSV file right? or are you returning raw data from the server and having the client create the CSV file?

Comment: The server is making the CSV file. The client side only create a file with the blob received.

Comment: Yeah, so the issue is on the server. You'll need to fix the server code that's generating the CSV.